# Can not install the spacegray-theme in gnu emacs

Tags: emacs

I tried following the instructions for installing the spacegray theme in emacs here: https://github.com/bruce/emacs-spacegray-theme

However when I typed spacegray-theme the minibuffer responsed with "[No match]". Is there something I need to know about emacs configurations? I'm still a newbie about this technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to type spacegray-theme in minibuffer.

Download `spacegray-theme.el` with package.el or download and put it to `~/.emacs.d/`. And add following expression to your configuration file(~/.emacs.d/init.el etc).

```
(load-theme 'spacegray t)
```

spacegray-theme is enabled after relaunching Emacs.